# Excel (Mac) updates, disable banner

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Excel's annoying update banner]

Is there a way to disable for ever and ever and ever this annoying banner?

I tried to remove the update service, I tried to set the updates to manual, I had it check for updates so that it could finally leave me alone...

And yet, it is still there...

Comment: I suppose choosing Check for Updates would be one way. It's usually a good idea to keep software up to date.

Comment: for ever and ever? Switch to libre-office.

Comment: when I check for the update, it tells me there are none and will ask again on restart